# Function to check if a list has no gaps

Tags: list, function, scala, scala-collections

I just want a function that returns `true` if all the elements of a `List[Integer]` follow each other, i.e.

```
noGaps(List(3,4,5)) // true
noGaps(List(4,3,5)) // false
noGaps(List(3,4,6)) // false
```

I have something that works but it's a bit verbose - what's the most elegant solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this?

```
def noGaps(xs: Seq[Int]) =
  xs.size < 2 || xs.sliding(2).forall { case Seq(x, y) => y == x + 1 }
```

Comment: I hereby name this the *"sliding rule"*: it always takes two tries to do it right. First you do it right. *Then* you do it right for cases when the seq size is less than the sliding window...

Comment: The scala standard library is still full of pleasant surprises for me. I didn't know about this method until you pointed it out.

Comment: nice solution.  without if statement it would be: xs.sliding(2).forall { case Seq(x, y) => y == x + 1; case _ => true }

Answer (score 0):

```
def noGaps(xs: Seq[Int]) = xs.isEmpty||xs.tail == xs.map(_+1).init
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it explicit that you compare the `List` to a [`Range`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html):

```
def noGaps(l: Seq[Int]): Boolean =
  l.isEmpty || l.sameElements(l.head to l.last)
```

Note that, although *elegant*, this is slightly less efficient than the [sliding solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6926831/9297144), due to `l.last` which is `O(n)`. If `n` is the size of the list and `i` the first element for which there is a gap (or `n` if no gap), then the sliding solution would be performed in `i` steps whereas this one is performed in `n + i` steps.